# Highcharts, load then refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts, settimeout, intervals

I have a highcharts chart running with ajax,

it gets the data and refreshes every 15 seconds which is perfectly fine

except, i need the chart to load striaght away and then refresh every 15seconds,

at the moment it waits 15 seconds before displaying on page load.

code below

```
function getLiveData() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-converted-data',
        success: function(point) {
            var x = (new Date()).getTime();
            console.log(point);
            var series = liveChart.series[0];
            var series1 = liveChart.series[1];
            var series2 = liveChart.series[2];
            var series3 = liveChart.series[3];
                shift = series.data.length > 20; 
                shift1 = series1.data.length > 20; 
                shift2 = series2.data.length > 20; 
                shift3 = series3.data.length > 20; 

            // add the points
            liveChart.series[0].addPoint([x, point[0]], true, shift);
            liveChart.series[1].addPoint([x, point[1]], true, shift1);
            liveChart.series[2].addPoint([x, point[2]], true, shift2);
            liveChart.series[3].addPoint([x, point[3]], true, shift3);

            // call it again after 15 seconds,
            //this is loading the actual chart every 15 seconds,
            //i need the chart to load instantly then refresh every 15 seconds, any ideas?
            setTimeout(getLiveData, 15000);    
        }, 
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Comment: You just need to call `getLiveData()` as soon as the page loads

Comment: wow, thanks, can't believe i missed that

Answer (score 0):

call your function when page loads. insert this after your code:

```
$(function() {
    getLiveData();
});
```